# Does the PDF $\exp\left(-\frac{x^2}{2}\right) \cosh(\gamma x)$ have a name?

Tags: normal-distribution, density-function, terminology

Is there a name for the following probability density function:
$$
P(x) \propto \exp\left(-\frac{x^2}{2}\right) \cosh(\gamma x)
$$
where $\gamma \ge 0$ and $x\in\mathbb{R}$?

Eventually my goal is to draw efficiently samples from $P(x)$.  If this distribution does not have a name, any suggestions on how I can draw samples from it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Since](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosinus_hyperbolique)
$$\cosh(\gamma x)=\dfrac{e^{\gamma x}+e^{-\gamma x}}{2}$$
one can rewrite the density as
$$
p(x)\propto \exp(-{x^2}/{2}) \{e^{\gamma x}+e^{-\gamma x}\}\\
\propto e^{-x^2/2+\gamma x}+e^{-x^2/2-\gamma x}\\
\propto e^{-(x-\gamma)^2/2}+e^{-(x+\gamma)^2/2}\\
$$
therefore this distribution is simply a mixture of two Normal distributions, $\mathcal N(\gamma,1)$ and $\mathcal N(-\gamma,1)$, with equal weights. Simulation (based on this representation) is thus obvious.

Comment: Ah that's obvious, don't know how I missed that. Thanks!