# Sampling from $P(x) \propto \cosh^{m}(a x) e^{-x^{2}/2}$

Tags: sampling, density-function, mixture-distribution, truncated-normal-distribution, accept-reject

Is there an efficient algorithm to draw samples $x \sim P(x)$ from the PDF:

$$
P(x) \propto \cosh^{m}(a x) e^{-x^{2}/2}
$$

where $a\ge0$ is a real parameter, and $m$ a positive integer?

Since this is a univariate PDF, my first attempt was to compute the CDF and use the inverse CDF method to sample it, but neither the CDF nor the inverse CDF seem to have a tractable analytical form.

Comment: Related: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/630463/5536 for the simpler $m=1$ case of this question.

Comment: By "$\cosh^m(ax)$", do you mean "$(\cosh(ax))^m$" or that $\cosh$ is applied $m$ times?

Comment: @mhdadk I mean $(\cosh(ax))^m$.

Comment: Can you provide values of $a$ and $m$ that would be of interest for you?

Comment: $m$ is a positive integer, and $a$ a positive real. @MattF.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The distribution that the OP seeks is a straightforward extension of the formula for the case $m=1$ that Xi'an derived in the linked answer.

Suppose that $P(x) \propto (\cosh(ax))^m \exp(-x^2/2)$.  Then, since
\begin{align}(\cosh(ax))^m &= \left(\frac{\exp(ax)+\exp(-ax)}{2}\right)^m\\
&= \sum_{k=0}^m 2^{-m} \binom{m}{k}\exp(akx)\exp(-a(m-k)x)\\
&= \sum_{k=0}^m 2^{-m} \binom{m}{k} \exp(-a(m-2k)x),
\end{align}
$P(x)$ is once again a *weighted* sum (also called a *mixture*) of normal distributions with means ranging from $-ma$ to $+ma$ in steps of $2a$. Note that the standard normal distribution is included in the mixture only when $m$ is even. The weights are given by the probability mass distribution function of a $(m,\frac 12)$ *binomial* random variable.

Turning to the actual question asked by the OP about an efficient algorithm for *sampling* from this distribution, consider the various answers to [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/70855/6633), some of which even contain R code with varying degrees of efficiency.

Comment: This is fine for *integral* $m$ -- but that's the easy case.

Comment: If I understand correctly, sampling $P(x)$ then amounts to drawing $k \sim \operatorname{Binom}(m,1/2)$ (which is easy), and then $x \sim \mathcal N(2ka, 1)$ (which is also easy) ?

Comment: @whuber I am interested in integer $m$

Comment: @a06e For integer $m$, the mean of each component is $-a(m-2k)$.

Comment: This, then, is a good answer +1.

Comment: @JarleTufto Right thanks.

Comment: +1 but don't the weights (prior to making them sum to 1) need to depend on $\mu_k=-a(m-2k)$?  $$\begin{align}(\cosh(ax))^m  \exp(-x^2/2)
 &= \sum_{k=0}^m 2^{-m} \binom{m}{k} \exp(-a(m-2k)x) \exp(-x^2/2) \\
 &= \sum_{k=0}^m 2^{-m} \binom{m}{k} \exp(\mu_k x-x^2/2) \\
 &= \sum_{k=0}^m 2^{-m} \binom{m}{k} \exp(\mu_k x-x^2/2 - \mu_k^2/2 + \mu_k^2/2) \\
 &= \sum_{k=0}^m 2^{-m} \binom{m}{k} \exp(\mu_k^2)\exp(-(x-\mu_k)^2/2)
\end{align}$$

Comment: The $\exp(\mu_k^2)$ in the last equation above should of course be $\exp(\mu_k^2/2)$.

Comment: @JimB  $P(x)$, the pdf of $X$ is _proportional_ to $\sum_{k=0}^m 2^{-m} \binom{m}{k} \exp(-a(m-2k)x)\exp(-x^2/2$, _not_ **equal** _to_  $\sum_{k=0}^m 2^{-m} \binom{m}{k} \exp(-a(m-2k)x)\exp(-x^2/2)$.  The $\exp(\mu_k^2/2)$ factors that you have discovered  are just part of the constant of proportionality.  The weights $2^{-m}\binom{m}{k}$ do sum to $1$.

Comment: I totally agree with your proportionality comment but $\exp(\mu_k^2/2)$ varies for every value of $k$ and therefore isn't a constant part of the constant of proportionality.  The weights (prior to dividing by the total of the weights) does need to include $\exp(\mu_k^2/2)$.  With values of $a>0$ and even relatively small values of $m$, the two extreme normal distributions (associated with $k=0$ and $k=m$)  completely dominate with all of the other standardized weights nearly zero.

Answer (score 6):

Building on the answer of Dilip, for non-integer $m$, letting $\{m\}=m-\lfloor m\rfloor$ denote the fractional part of $m$, and using the fact that $\cosh x\le \exp|x|$, the (unnormalized) target density can be rewritten as
$$
\begin{align}
f(x)&=\cosh^m(ax)\exp(-x^2/2)
\\&=\cosh^{\{m\}}(ax)\cosh^{\lfloor m\rfloor} (ax)\exp(-x^2/2)
\\&\le \exp(a\{m\}|x|)\cosh^{\lfloor m\rfloor} (ax)\exp(-x^2/2)
\\&= \sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor m\rfloor} 2^{-{\lfloor m\rfloor}} \binom{{\lfloor m\rfloor}}{k} \exp\Big(-x^2/2-a({\lfloor m\rfloor}-2k)x+a\{m\}|x|\Big).
\end{align}
$$
Like the target $f(x)$, the right hand side is symmetric around zero.  For $x\ge 0$, it is proportional to the density of a mixture of $\lfloor m\rfloor+1$ Gaussian distributions truncated below zero.  Completing the square in $x$, the mean (before truncation) of component $k$ is
$$
\mu_k=-a(\lfloor m\rfloor-\{m\}-2k)
$$
and the associated weights are
$$
w_k \propto \Phi(\mu_k)\binom{\lfloor m\rfloor}{k}e^{\mu_k^2/2}.
$$

We can easily simulate proposals efficiently from this mixture (using the alias and inversion methods), and then obtain samples from $f(x)$ by accepting the proposals with probabilities given by $f(x)$ divided by the above right hand side.

The acceptance probability simplifies to
$$
\left(\frac{1+\exp(-2a|x|)}{2}\right)^{\{m\}}>\frac1{2^{\{m\}}}
$$
so the overall acceptance probabilty is always greater than 1/2.

R implementation:

```r
dcoshgauss <- function(x, a, m)  
  cosh(a*x)^m*exp(-x^2/2)
rcoshgauss <- function(n, a, m) {
  floorm <- floor(m)
  fractm <- m - floorm
  kk <- 0:floorm
  mu <- -a*(floorm - fractm - 2*kk)
  w <- pnorm(mu)*choose(floorm, kk)*exp(mu^2/2)
  w <- w/sum(w)
  xx <- numeric(n)
  i <- 0
  s <- 0
  while (i < n) {
    k <- sample(kk+1, size = 1, prob=w)
    u <- runif(1, pnorm(-mu[k]), 1)
    x <- mu[k] + qnorm(u)
    acceptprob <- ((1+exp(-2*x*a))/2)^fractm
    u <- runif(1)
    s <- s + 1
    if (u<acceptprob) {
      sign <- sample(c(-1,1), 1)
      x <- sign*x
      i <- i + 1
      xx[i] <- x
    }
  }
  cat("Acceptance probability was",n/s,"\n")
  xx
}

set.seed(1)
x <- rcoshgauss(1e6, 1, 2.9)
#> Acceptance probability was 0.5489607
hist(x, breaks=200, xlim=c(-8,8), main="")
```

[image]

```r
curve(dcoshgauss(x, 1, 2.9), -8,8)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2024-01-28 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Ah I almost missed this wonderful answer, thanks!

Comment: @a06e Thanks, this was a neat problem!

Answer (score 2):

This is just an extended comment.

With the restriction of the values of $m$ being positive integers there is an analytic solution of a mixture of normals each with variance 1 as shown by @DilipSarwate (although I currently disagree about the weights).  However, showing graphic examples should almost always be considered in which interesting features can appear.

In this case when $a$ and $m$ are large enough (and they don't need to be very large) one is essentially sampling from a mixture of just two normals with means of opposite sign and variance 1.  This might also be the case for large values of $m$ when $m$ is not an integer.

Below are a few examples showing the resulting density (blue) and the individual contributions (red).

**Small $a$ and small $m$**
[image: Small a and small m]

**$a=1$ and $m=2$**
[image: a=1 and m=2]

**$a=1$ and $m=3$**
[image: a=1 and m=3]

**$a=1$ and $m=4$**
[image: a=1 and m=4]